# Issue regarding Launch Modes in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I have gone through below documentation link :

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242

Here, I understood the working of all the four Launch Modes namely :

> Standard, SingleTop, SingleTask, SingleInstance.

Also got cleared about doing it practically by adding attribute `'android:launchMode'` in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Issue is with adding flags in Activity programmatically.

Now, From the Documentation it is said that :

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>
> This flag works similar to “launchMode = singleTask”.

Now, To understood the behaviour of this, First I have checked it using AndroidManifest.xml.
I have taken four Activities in my Project : A, B, C, D.
Setted `“launchMode = singleTask”` to my Activity C.

Navigation is like this From A -> B -> C -> D and from D -> C.

So, When I going from D to C its not creating new Activity C but letting me to Activity C. This is fine. Understood.

**Now, I want to understood the same thing Programmatically.**

So, For that I have removed static `“launchMode = singleTask”` from the AndroidManifest.xml and doing it inside Activity C like below :

```
startActivity(Intent(ActivityC@this,ActivityD::class.java).setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```

and In Activity D I have done as below :

```
startActivity(Intent(ActivityD@this,ActivityC::class.java))
```

But, this programmatic things not working like as I have done it with AndroidManifest.xml, It's opening New Activity C... instead of Going back towards Activity C.

What might be the issue ? or am I doing something wrong here ? Pls. guide. Thanks.

Comment: The special launch modes `singleTask` and `singleInstance` are dependent on the use of `taskAffinity`. This can be very complicated. If you aren't using `taskAffinity` then your special launch modes aren't working the way you think they should anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation,

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK produces the same behavior as the "singleTask"
> launchMode value.

So your going wrong in Activity D where you start Activity C. You should do,

```
startActivity(Intent(ActivityD@this,ActivityC::class.java)).setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```

Setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK when starting Activity D from C is not relevant.

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: tried doing it. but it still opening new Actvity C from Activity D instead of going back to Activity C.

Comment: Try using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

startActivity(Intent(ActivityD@this,ActivityC::class.java)).setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))

Comment: I want to understand the use of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK